# QGIS 3.22 world files not reading correctly

Tags: qgis, world-file

I have just upgraded to QGIS 3.22.3-Białowieża.
When I add a Tiff with a world file .tfw the image comes in the wrong size (twice the size it should be). The same files work fine in 3.18 and the world file seems fine. The pixel size should be 1m but in QGIS 3.22 they measure as 2m. I have checked cRS setting and that all seems correct.

```
1.0000000000
0.0000000000
0.0000000000
-1.0000000000
515000.5000000000
169999.5000000056
```

Comment: how are you measuring them? which CRS are you using?

Comment: measured using the distance tool and compared to other data. EPSG 27700.  Data is LiDAR from DEFRA https://environment.data.gov.uk/DefraDataDownload/?Mode=survey

Comment: Which product? There seems to be 2m and 1m resolutions available, I guess you have 1m. Even better if you tell exactly the filename/tile that you have.

Comment: National-LIDAR-Programme-VOM-2021-TQ16ne  Galsworthy Road, Kingston Upon Thames

Answer (score 1):

Works for me with QGIS 3.23

I downloaded National-LIDAR-Programme-VOM-2021-TQ16ne.zip and opened the both tif files from the zip into QGIS project having CRS EPSG:27700. Then I zoomed in to see the individual pixels.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I am guessing its an issue with OSX or my user preferences but havn't traced it yet.

Comment: It is very odd behavior. What pixel size does gdalinfo report for you?

Comment: Origin = (515000.000000000000000,170000.000000005587935)
Pixel Size = (1.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000)

Comment: I do not understand how on earth that file can show a pixel size of 2 meters. If opened into a project with unsuitable CRS and if Cartesian measurement method is selected then that could be possible but that should not be your case.

Comment: Its one of the oddest things I have experienced with QGIS. I tried manually editing the world file to see what would happen if I set the pixel size to 0.5m - this made the pixels 1m at some zoom levels but not at others. I am on mac which can cause issues but otherwise its a clean install with my user preferences wiped out to get GRASS and SAGA running

Comment: Are you comparing that image with some tiled image layer like OpenStreetMap or why do you speak about zoom levels?

Comment: no just different scales on screen

Comment: World file plays probably no role because the tiff seems to be GeoTIFF. I guess that you can move the tfw file away and image still opens in correct place.